# How can I have different listviews on one page depending on what you clicked on the previous page?

Tags: c#, forms, listview, xamarin

The page where the user clicks either 1 or 2 and you get pushed to the same page, but I want it to be a unique list for each category clicked. So, when you click on `Clickthis1` you'll get a ListView only `Clickthis1` people can access and if you click on `Clickthis2` you'll get a list only visible if you clicked `Clickthis2`.

```
void Clickthis1 (object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var CategoryName = new StartPage();

    CategoryName.TheCategoryName ("Beatrice", /* the list here?*/);

    Navigation.PushAsync (CategoryName);
}

void Clickthis2 (object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var CategoryName = new StartPage();

    CategoryName.TheCategoryName ("Anna", /* the list here?*/);


    Navigation.PushAsync(CategoryName);
}
```

And this is the page where the info gets pushed into and where I have the list. I am not sure how I should proceed however.

```
List<createSomething> ourPitems = new List<createSomething>();


public StartPage ()
{
    InitializeComponent ();
}

public class createSomething
{
    public string ourUsername {get; set;}
}


public void TheCategoryName (String pHeader, /*New list added here???*/)
{

    personHeader.Text = pHeader;

}

protected override void OnAppearing(){
getItems (); }

async void getItems () 
{
var getItems = await parseAPI.myInfo (Application.Current.Properties 
["sessionToken"].ToString ());
EmployeeList.ItemsSource = null;



ourPitems = new List<createSomething> ();

foreach (var currentItem in getItems["results"]) 
{
ourPitems.Add (new createSomething ()


{

ourUsername = currentItem ["YourName"].ToString (),
});}

EmployeeList.ItemsSource = ourPitems;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you choose to use public properties instead of overloading your constructor:

In your calling page (StartPage?), pass in the Category Name:

```
void Clickthis1 (object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    startPage= new StartPage(); 
    startPage.CategoryName = categoryName;
    Navigation.PushAsync (startPage));
}
```

Then in your second page (which I'll call ListPage)

```
class ListPage : ContentPage
{
    public ListPage()
    {
        getItems ();
    }

    private string categoryName; 
    public string TheCategoryName 
    { 
        get { return categoryName; }
        set { categoryName= value; }
    }
```

Then use the category in your list-building method:

```
async void getItems () 
{
    var items = await parseAPI.myInfo (Application.Current.Properties[categoryName].ToString ());

    ...
}
```

Comment: What would you say is the easiest way based on my currentcode? I kinda get what you mean but i am not 100 % sure how i should execute it.

Comment: I've moved #2 to #1 and added some code. I'm not sure how you plan to access Beatrice or Anna in the Properties class, are you?

Comment: Simplified further and assumed that the CategoryName should be passed into the Property collection.

Comment: How did your first code look? The one that said something with: if (categoryName == "beatrice"), i think that might work better in my particular case because i do not store the categoryname anywhere

Comment: (define getItems)

if (categoryName = "Beatrice")
{
  getItems = parseAPI.myInfo (Application.Current.Properties ["Beatrice"].ToString ());
}
else if (categoryName = "Anna")
{
  getItems = parseAPI.myInfo (Application.Current.Properties ["Anna"].ToString ());
}

Comment: How should i push it?

void Clickthis (object sender, EventArgs args)
  {
   var CategoryName = new StartPage(CategoryName.TheCategoryName ("Beatrice"));


   Navigation.PushAsync (CategoryName);
  }

does not seem to work.

Comment: Navigation.PushAsync (new StartPage(CategoryName));

Pass Xamarin.Forms params to a Page using constructor.

Comment: Passing via constructor is quick, but you can also assign a public param:

startPage= new StartPage();
startPage.CategoryName = categoryName;
Navigation.PushAsync (startPage));

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to pass the param two ways, in a public property AND through the constructor.  You need to pick one.  In the last two comments I showed both ways you can do it.

Comment: when i use startPage= new StartPage(); startPage.CategoryName = categoryName; Navigation.PushAsync (startPage)); i get errors

Comment: Here's a template for choosing from a list and passing the result to another page:  https://github.com/danhermes/xamarin-book-examples/blob/master/Chapter%206%20-%20Navigation/NavigationExamples/NavigationExamples/DrilldownListViewByItem.cs

Comment: I changed TheCategoryName  to CategoryName but its up to you.  Your TheCategoryName property is not a C# standard property. Consider googling C# properties and standardize it.

Comment: Well we have a string on our startpage so i have to add something in new startpage (/*in here*/); but the question is what

Comment: It means that it is not expected a parameter in the constructor call. So go into StartPage and remove all params from the constructor  "()". But leave TheCategoryName property alone.

Comment: ok so i delete this then: public StartPage(/*String categoryName*/ delete that), but how can i then connect the app.curr.prop [categoryName]?

Comment: well yeah, "the categoryName" does not exist in the current context, as i removed it.::: parseAPI.getInfo (Application.Current.Properties [categoryName].ToString ());

Comment: You need to build the TheCategoryName property correctly in StartPage.

private string categoryName;

public string TheCategoryName 
{
    get { return categoryName; }
    set { categoryName= value; }
}

Comment: Then use categoryName in StartPage however and wherever you need to.

Comment: damn im so lost now.. should i put it into a void or inside the public startpage () { here? )

Comment: Do you know how to code a C# property? (TheCategoryName)

Comment: I don't think so. I know how to make public classes and all that and make like global strings

Comment: Look at this: http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/classes/properties/
and read up on C# properties in general.  You'll never get anywhere with this language without better background on properties.

Then take all of this and overwrite your entire definition of TheCategoryName in StartPage:

private string categoryName; public string TheCategoryName { get { return categoryName; } set { categoryName= value; } }

Comment: okok, now i atleast get no error but it does however not work but it is running. i got this now: http://pastebin.com/7p5tnrfH

Comment: Your TheCategoryName property looks good.  Now to instantiate the StartPage.  I've given you everything you need to get this working.  Please read back though the comments.

Comment: Yeah I am :( Still can't get it to work. It is hard to read code when it is typed in this format. I understand if u don't feel the urge to help anymore :P I am very new so iam slow :/

Comment: Forget Xamarin for awhile, I suggest that after reading up on properties, that you study these instantiation examples until you understand every line: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx  and this  http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rmcochran/instantiationI06232007000158AM/instantiationI.aspx

Comment: Code updated up top so its easier to read.  Please note that there are two pages: StartPage and ListPage

Comment: ahhhhh so i have to create another page, but what if I have like 12 different options? do i need to create 12 different pages then?

Comment: One page, if your data source can accept a Category param.  Again, look at this, with a list page where each item points to the detail page: https://github.com/danhermes/xamarin-book-examples/blob/master/Chapter%206%20-%20Navigation/NavigationExamples/NavigationExamples/DrilldownListViewByItem.cs