# How can I have different lists (with 1 list) depending on what you click on the previous page?

Tags: c#, forms, list, xamarin

So what I want is where the user clicks either 1,2 or 3 and you get pushed to the same page, but I want it to be a unique list for each category clicked. So, when you click on Clickthis1 you'll get a ListView only Clickthis1 people can access and if you click on Clickthis2 you'll get a list only visible if you clicked Clickthis2 and so on.

This is the code of the first page where you click the category of your choice and depending on where you clicked should get unique listviews:

```
void Clickthis1 (object sender, EventArgs args)
{
var CategoryName = new StartPage();

CategoryName.TheCategoryName ("Info1", /* the list here?*/);

Navigation.PushAsync (CategoryName);
}


void Clickthis2 (object sender, EventArgs args)
{
var CategoryName = new StartPage();

CategoryName.TheCategoryName ("Info2", /* the list here?*/);


Navigation.PushAsync(CategoryName);
}

void Clickthis3 (object sender, EventArgs args)
{
var CategoryName = new StartPage();

CategoryName.TheCategoryName ("Info3", /* the list here?*/);


Navigation.PushAsync(CategoryName);
}
```

And this is the page where the info gets pushed into and where I have the list. I am not sure how I should proceed from here.

```
List<createSomething> ourPitems = new List<createSomething>();


public StartPage (){
InitializeComponent ();}

public class createSomething{
public string ourUsername {get; set;}
}


public void TheCategoryName (String pHeader, /*New list added here??? */)
{

personHeader.Text = pHeader;

}

protected override void OnAppearing(){
getItems (); }

async void getItems () 
{
var getItems = await parseAPI.myInfo (Application.Current.Properties 
["sessionToken"].ToString ());
EmployeeList.ItemsSource = null;



ourPitems = new List<createSomething> ();

foreach (var currentItem in getItems["results"]) 
{
ourPitems.Add (new createSomething ()


{

ourUsername = currentItem ["YourName"].ToString (),
});}

EmployeeList.ItemsSource = ourPitems;

}
```

Comment: You asked this same question last week: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34253061/how-can-i-have-different-listviews-on-one-page-depending-on-what-you-clicked-on

Comment: It is not my question but I am looking for the same solution so I copied some of his text. There is an answer there on his thread but I can't quite get the solution that the guy there brought up.

Comment: Is there no other way around? I am having alot of trouble when I try to execute his method.

Comment: Or maybe explain it in an easier way